# What's the difference between "give out" and "give away"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the difference between "give out" and "give away" as in telling someone the truth or giving someone the information accidentally?

Answer (score 1):

In the U.K. we don't "give out the truth" but we might:

**[disseminate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disseminate) information** (either the truth or indeed falsehoods)

also we only ever "give away" the indefinite article, for instance:

Mark told Phillipa about the mistake he made. **He's given it away now!**

Answer (score 0):

To this US English speaker, **give out** implies distributing something widely, whereas **give away** sounds more like it refers to just one incident or person.  Loosely, *give away* = "make something known", but *give out* = "distribute".

For example,

> During the interview, the director **gave away** the secret ending of the movie.

but not

> During the interview, the director <s>gave out</s> the secret ending of the movie.

But

> The guard **gave out** the password to anyone who asked for it.

sounds more natural than

> The guard <s>gave away</s> the password to anyone who asked for it.